# Making a powerbank using lead-acid batteries

Tags: power, batteries, power-electronics, charge, lead-acid

I have three 12 V, 12 Ah deep-cell lead-acid batteries wired in series that were used for a scooter. I’d like to repurpose this battery pack into a powerbank that can be used to charge electronic devices.

How could I go about turning this 36 V battery pack into a safe way to charge my laptop, which uses a 40 VAC adapter for a wall outlet (or charge a phone, etc.)?

Comment: 40 V ac adapter? 240V you mean? Or is it a universal 110 to 240V AC?

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in your question. Like Passerby suspects, a 40 V AC adapter sound highly unusual. You may also tell your laptops model to add more info. What else do you intend to charge?

Answer (score 1):

Use an inverter for mains AC and possibly a DC to DC converter to power chargers at 12V.

But put the batteries in parallel and get a 12v inverter - which is probably cheaper anyway.

How will you be charging these batteries? Also consider all the extra bits like fuses needed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to break the series connection, equalize the batteries, and connect them in parallel as there are far more consumer accessories for 12V systems than 36V systems.  I would get an inverter with USB outputs as @Solar Mike suggests.  Trying to get 40V straight into your laptop would require a DC/DC converter which would cost on par with the inverter and might not even work since many laptops require a data handshake from the "official" charger brick.  Another option would be a laptop charger designed to work from a cigarette lighter outlet.

I bet if you look around you can find modules that have both cigarette lighter sockets and USB sockets that can be attached directly to the battery.  This should also take care of USB PD negotiation.

Comment: Would you recommend something like this? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MR569GA/ref=ox_sc_saved_title_1?smid=A2YZ44EQE6CQC7&th=1

Comment: That kind of thing would work, though I have no experience with the brand.  It's a bit of a gamble to distinguish between "crappy product", "good product", and "crappy product wrapped in a good product's hide".